# Replace strings in Python

Tags: python, string, replace, str-replace

I have a string:

```
string = '17 121221 17 17939 234343 17 39393'
```

How do I make sure that when using string.replace('17', 'sth') only the 17s are replaced (but not 17 which is a part of 17939)?

I would like an output string like:

```
string = 'sth 121221 sth 17939 234343 sth 39393'
```

Cheers,
Kate

Comment: @RajeshKumar, That fails with 123 345 12317 1234 since it also replaces the 17 in 12317 which the OP doesn't want

Comment: @sshashank124 it actually works if I do string.replace(' 17 ', 'sth')!

Comment: But that would fail if 17 is at the start and end of the string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish that using `regex`:

```
import re

string = '17 121221 17 17939 234343 17 39393'

>>> print re.sub(r'(\D|^)17(\D|$)', r'\1sth\2', string)
sth 121221 sth 17939 234343 sth 39393
```

Comment: this is going to fail when there's a number "-17" in the string, and in a few other cases as well.

Answer (score 1):

much easier to use and fail-proof:

```
>>> string = '17 121221 17 17939 234343 17 39393'
>>> ' '.join( 'sth' if i == '17' else i for i in string.split() )
'sth 121221 sth 17939 234343 sth 39393'
```

you should not use regex when a simple `split/join` is sufficient.